# pdo exception driver not found in laravel for sqlite

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel-5, pdo

When I run `php artisan migrate` command I get:

> [PDOException] could not find driver.

I made my default database as sqlite and checked whether there are pdo drivers for sqlite using `php -i` command. I could not understand my problem.

Comment: Is your driver actually installed? Is it enabled in your php.ini?

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: anyone discovered the witchcraft?? Same error here...

Answer (score 46):

Your system has missing `php` `SQLite` installation.

Install it by using:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-sqlite
```

Then restart your apache server

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

Comment: Help out. I intend to use sqlite for testing, I've set my database to `storage_path('test.sqlite')` in database.php config file. I'm assuming that `test.sqlite` should be a binary file. How do I create `test.sqlite`? Do I just create a file with the `.sqlite` extension?

Comment: For php 7.1 just use sudo apt-get install php7.1-sqlite

Comment: Note that the sqlite module for PHP is its own package that must be installed in addition to sqlite itself. (For Arch linux the package name is `php-sqlite`.) You must also enable the `pdo_sqlite.so` and `sqlite3.so` extensions in your php.ini.

Answer (score 17):

You need to install PDO on your server **OR** you can just uncomment the following line in your `php.ini` config file.

> To find the `php.ini` file, you can run `php-config` to show you where it's located.

Remove the comment character `;` **from**:

```
;extension=pdo_sqlite
```

**to**:

```
extension=pdo_sqlite
```

Finally, save the change and restart your server.

Answer (score 5):

For those using Windows and Xampp
Just uncomment theses lines in php.ini :

```
extension=pdo_sqlite

extension=sqlite3
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using sqlite and try to alter a table or drop a column you have to require `doctrine/dbal`, as suggested in the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#dropping-columns).

Just do a `composer require doctrine/dbal` and retry your migration.

Answer (score 0):

1. install php extension for sqlite `apt --yes install php8.2-sqlite3` (for php 8.2)
2. go to `.env` file, set `DB_CONNECTION=sqlite` and **comment** another options: `DB_HOST`, `DB_PORT`, `DB_DATABASE`, `DB_USERNAME`, `DB_PASSWORD` and add `DB_FOREIGN_KEYS=true`

   > DB_CONNECTION=sqlite

   > #DB_HOST=

   > #DB_PORT=

   > #DB_DATABASE=

   > #DB_DATABASE=

   > #DB_USERNAME=

   > #DB_PASSWORD=

   > DB_FOREIGN_KEYS=true
3. edit `php.ini`: find `;extension=pdo_sqlite` and remove `;` and save file
4. restart php `sudo service php8.2-fpm restart`
5. make permissions for `database/database.sqlite` as `0777`
6. run `php artisan migrate`

also **do not make changes** at `config/database.php` in `sqlite` section, it has to be

```
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
```

Answer (score -3):

I'm using Laravel 5.3 and I had to comment out some params in .env file.

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
# DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
# DB_PORT=3306
# DB_DATABASE=homestead
# DB_USERNAME=homestead
# DB_PASSWORD=secret
```